# My hard drives are losing files during backup

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have two Western Digital Passport drives and I am seeking to backup data from one to another. Once the backup is done (the loading bar finishes), Windows says certain files could not be transferred. Then it asks me to Retry or Skip. Retrying never works. As a result, I cannot seem to backup my work properly.

I have 12-14 million files on my drives. What do I do?

Comment: This is a guess, but perhaps you have another program running and those files are locked?

Comment: Or you have ownership/rights issues. Moved files retain ownership from the original location and you might not have the ownership or permissions granted to your user to do the operation.